# How to print the classnames that are kryo serialized

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, serialization, kryo

I am using `Spark`(scala) with `Kryo` serialization.

I want to enumerate all the class names and print them to know what are the classes which are `Kryo` serialized at run-time pro-grammatically and I don't have a clue for doing this.

Why I need this because...  `Kryo` [docs](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo#using-standard-java-serialization) says that some of the classes, which  may use java serialization which might be slow. so I want to cross check what are those classes.

Comment: I might be wrong but internal structs storing registered classes are protected. Maybe with `spark.kryo.registrationRequired`, but it is brute force...

Comment: in fact this is the only way I found. Thx!